# Get application element

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have a toolbar button and a command tied to this button. I need to make this button disabled and enabled in this command. How I can get this button from a command? And more in general: How I can get an element of eclipse rcp application? For example, to get a view by id, get a command by id, get an active view.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button name is button1, you can enable it by :

button1.setEnabled(true);

And disable it by:

button1.setEnabled(false);